# Android: InputMethodService.Dialog.setOnKeyListener not taking any key events

Tags: android, service, dialog, onkeylistener

I'm trying to create a `custom ime` for the Android TV similar to the "`Leanback Keyboard`" app. The issue I have right now is that I need to process `KeyEvents` (we have a remote control and I need to listen to `D-pad inputs` specifically). Because I need to use a `service` (InputMethodService), I can not use `setOnKeyListener` on it unlike an Activity. But since `InputMethodService` actually uses a dialog to output some UI on the screen, then maybe I could use the `dialog's setOnKeyListener` instead. I've tried the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends InputMethodService implements DialogInterface.OnKeyListener {

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    layout_root = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    ...

    getWindow().takeKeyEvents(true);
    getWindow().setOnKeyListener(this);

    return layout_root;
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

I've even explicitly made every view in xml to be `unfocusable` to make sure that the `dialog gets the OnKey events`:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

I understand that Services do not get OnKey events but InputMethodService is outputting some UI elements and I feel like there should be a way.

My last resort is for the InputMethodService to start a transparent Activity that listens to KeyEvents and broadcasts it back to the InputMethodService. I don't really want to do that since I'm not even sure it'll work.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `InputMethodServce` has `onKeyDown`, `onKeyUp`, `onKeyLongPress` and `onKeyMultiple` methods that you overwrite.